# Computing LF/HF frequency bands for an R-R array

Tags: python, fft, frequency, spectrum

Assume `RR` is the array containing the R-R intervals of an ECG (in milliseconds).

Which is the correct method for computing the HF and LF frequency bands? I don't get the point, because I find apparently conflicting works that confuse me, i.e., :

- Some works in the literature (e.g., [1] and [2]) talk about extracting the frequency bands from the absolute power (i.e., expressed as `ms^2/Hz`);
- Some other references (e.g., [3]) extract them just from `abs(fft)`.

Can you help me in constructing the Python snippet for extracting them, and the theoretical explanation of it?  Thanks!

---

*References*

[1] "An overview of HRV metrics and norms", Shaffer and Ginsberg

[2] "Thermal comfort and stress recognition in office environment", Nkurikiyeyezu et al.

[3] http://www.paulvangent.com/2016/03/21/analyzing-a-discrete-heart-rate-signal-using-python-part-2/